# Adding node modules to gitignore

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have asked this one on quite a few forums i. e. 
Why do we add node modules to gitignore.  Doesn't it have our project dependencies.?
When a user copies my repo and run it in its local,  it should all for dependencies.

Comment: For _node.js_ all dependencies should be listed within your `package.json`, so you won't need to add your *node_module*  directory into version control, but you could argue that it might be also a good idea to keep it under version control, so that you can always be sure that you have all modules when you do a  roll out, even if _npm_  is down. But might be problematic with modules that have native code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dependencies are listed in the file [package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json) and must be shared to have other user to load same modules. The folder node_modules contains the loaded modules when `npm install` command loads the modules listed in package.json.

The loaded node modules are to heavy to be shared directly, that's why this folder must be ignore when committing code to the shared repository.

NB: to share specific version of node modules whith other user, you can use a [shrinkwrap file](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/shrinkwrap)

Comment: So if i deploy my code on any server., how's the modukes are taken care of?

Comment: The command `npm install` will have to be launched in the root repository if the server allows an internet connection. Another solution is to use your own repositories manager like [nexus](https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/index.html) to override npm and share preloaded modules within a project team or through servers.Otherwise copy/paste will be the last solution :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use the command `npm install --save express` to install express.js for example the package.json file in your project will be updated with that dependency.

If you then do `npm install` it will automatically install all dependencies listed in your package.json file!

So then you just need to include your package.json file in your git repo.

Answer (score 0):

Even I thought the same earlier, later I realiser, too many of js files, if you notice there will be 2000-4000 is supported files in node modules folder, it's difficult to maintain.

Main reason is when back end builds happening, build system tries to bundle all these files even though they are not used in production environment because they are physically available in the codebase.

So it's good to ignore those files so that build times will be reduced.